# Topology. In the $\ell^2$ space. Is the following set compact, bounded and/or closed?

Tags: metric-spaces, normed-spaces

I have been given a problem regarding $\ell^2$ space.

> [image: Problem in question]

So. Since it's not a finite dimensional problem I know that closed and bounded does not imply compact. I do not have a great deal of experience in dealing with $\ell^2$ space so I think a lot of the confusion stems from that fact.

- I know for closed I need to show that the set contains all limits of its convergent sequences.
- For compact, I'm thinking I can use the fact that sequential compactness is the same thing as compact (in metric spaces).

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Look at the sequence $\{e_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$ when $e_i=(0,...,0,1,0,0,...)$, the $1$ being in coordinate number $i$. This is a sequence of vectors with norm $1$. Now, what is the norm of $e_i-e_j$ when $i\ne j$? Is there any chance this sequence has a convergent subsequence?

Comment: Thank you for the hint, very much appreacited. I think the norm is constant when $i ≠ j$. Does this mean that it is bounded? I believe that sequence can never be a convergent, therefore the set is not compact. (Not sure if I understood everything)

Comment: It is constant indeed. If $i\ne j$ then $||e_i-e_j||=\sqrt{2}$. So there is no way we can find a Cauchy subsequence here. Hence there is no convergent subsequence, and the set is not compact. The set is obviously bounded because the norm of all vectors in it is $1$. And since the set is a sphere it is also closed. (this is true in any metric space). So it is indeed an example of a set which is closed and bounded but not compact.